# Connecting my backend from frontend throws error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import img from "../../../public/images/shared/audiophile-logo.svg";
import axios from "axios"
import { useState } from "react";




const Signup = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "/api/auth/signup",
      { name, email, password }
    );
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
     
        <div className="w-[90%] my-auto mx-auto  text-left border-2 rounded-md border-black lg:w-[30%]">
          <div className=" mt-5  text-center w-full h-9 ">
          <h1 className="text-4xl font-semibold font-mono">audiophile</h1>
          </div>
          
            <form className="flex gap-5 flex-col w-[70%] mx-auto py-7">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input
                className="border-2 h-9  border-slate-700 rounded-xl"
                name="name"
                placeholder="name"
                type="text"
             onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}
              />
              <label>Email</label>
              <input name="email"
                       className="border-2 h-9  border-slate-700 rounded-xl"
                        placeholder="email"
                         type="email"
                         onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}
                          />
                            
              <label>Password</label>
              <input   className="border-2 h-9  rounded-xl border-slate-700"
               name="password" 
               placeholder="password" 
               type="password"
            onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)} 
            />
                    
            </form>
            <div className="w-full  pb-5 flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
                <button onClick={handleSubmit} className="bg-black w-[70%] h-8 rounded-xl text-white font-thin " >Create an Account</button>
                <Link to="/login" className="">Already have a account? <span className="hover:text-yellow-500g">Login</span></Link>
            </div>
       
          </div>
        </div>
     
    
  );`
};
export default Signup;
```

This is my code for singup and whenever i send data to backend i am getting error

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …} code :  "ERR_BAD_REQUEST" config :  {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …} message :  "Request failed with status code 404" name :  "AxiosError" request :  XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …} response :  {data: '', status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …} stack :  "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=ed092713:1180:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=ed092713:1404:7)" [[Prototype]] :  Error

i already added proxy to vite config file and my backend is working well when i test it

Tried multiple ways to solve but nothing worked.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Request failed with status code 404 usually means the backend route URL is wrong. Check the URL in developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

in your endpoint you should add your **port number** defined in your backend
like this

```js
try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup",
      { name, email, password }
    );
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

3000 is the port number defined in backend

Comment: Thanks for reply but can it be accessible  by adding proxy,like if i add like the code you replied it shows i needed cors.

Comment: const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

you can add these in your backend

Comment: Thanks, it works.But when i build mern app previously i just added proxy and it was working perfectly fine,but not in this case